# Connection error for cassandra and influxdb when using docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, cassandra, influxdb

I am using `docker-compose` for `influxdb` and `Cassandra` for my application but when I am trying to run application locally on my mac system I am getting below error - I am new for both so not sure where to make the changes for `IPs` for both docker images.

for Cassandra -

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused"), '::1': error(99, "Tried connecting to [('::1', 9042, 0, 0)]. Last error: Cannot assign requested address")})
```

For Influxdb - when trying to create a user programmatically

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: influxdb
```

Comment: Is your application running in a container? If so, are those in the same network? do you have an example of your `docker-compose`? thanks

Comment: Are you able to connect to your Cassandra instance on 127.0.0.1 with other methods (cqlsh)?  If it's running, it might be bound to another IP.

Comment: I am able to connect to Cassandra and also able to solve cassandra problem but still I am facing `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: influxdb` this issue